# How is this collection a base of Vietoris topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space and $\mathcal K(X)$ the collection of all non-empty closed subsets of $X$. Let
$$
U^+ := \{K \in \mathcal K(X) \mid K \cap U \neq \emptyset\} \quad \text{and} \quad U^- := \{K \in \mathcal K(X) \mid K \subset U\} \quad \forall U \in \tau.
$$

The [Vietoris topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2159730/1019043)  $\mathcal T$ of $\mathcal K(X)$ is defined as the one generated by the subbase $\mathcal B :=\{U^+, U^- \mid U  \in \tau\}$. Clearly,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal B_1 &:= \left \{ \bigg ( \bigcap_{i=1}^m U_i^+ \bigg ) \cap \bigg ( \bigcap_{j=1}^n V_i^- \bigg ) \,\middle\vert\, m,n \in \mathbb N^*;U_1, \ldots, U_m,V_1, \ldots, V_n \in \tau \right\} \\
&= \left \{ \bigg ( \bigcap_{i=1}^m U_i^+ \bigg ) \cap \bigg ( \bigcap_{j=1}^n V_i \bigg )^- \,\middle\vert\, m,n \in \mathbb N^*;U_1, \ldots, U_m,V_1, \ldots, V_n \in \tau \right\} \\
&= \left \{ \bigg ( \bigcap_{i=1}^m U_i^+ \bigg ) \cap V^- \,\middle\vert\, m \in \mathbb N^*;U_1, \ldots, U_m,V \in \tau \right\}
\end{align}
$$
is a base of $\mathcal T$. It is mentioned in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198778/1019043) that
$$
\mathcal B_2 := \left \{ \bigg ( \bigcap_{i=1}^m U_i^+ \bigg ) \cap \bigg ( \bigcup_{i=1}^m U_i \bigg )^- \,\middle\vert\, m \in \mathbb N^*;U_1, \ldots, U_m \in \tau \right\}
$$
is also a base of $\mathcal T$. Below is my attempt to verify this claim.

---

**My attempt:** It's clear that $\mathcal B_2 \subset \mathcal B_1$. Notice that
$$
(U^+ \cap X^+) \cap (U \cup X)^- = U^+ \quad \text{and} \quad (U^+ \cap \emptyset^+) \cap (U \cup \emptyset)^- = U^-.
$$

So $\mathcal B \subset \mathcal B_2$. It suffices to prove that $\mathcal B_2$ is stable under finite intersection. Let $m, n \in \mathbb N^*;U_1, \ldots, U_m, V_1, \ldots, V_n \in \tau$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
& \bigg ( \bigcap_{i=1}^m U_i^+ \bigg ) \cap \bigg ( \bigcup_{i=1}^m U_i \bigg )^-  \cap \bigg ( \bigcap_{i=1}^n V_i^+ \bigg ) \cap \bigg ( \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i \bigg )^-  \\
=& \bigg ( \bigcap_{i=1}^m U_i^+ \cap \bigcap_{i=1}^n V_i^+ \bigg ) \cap \bigg [ \bigg (\bigcup_{i=1}^m U_i \bigg ) \cap \bigg ( \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i  \bigg ) \bigg ]^- \\
=&  \bigg [ \bigcup_{\substack{i= 1, \ldots, m \\ j = 1, \ldots, n}} (U^+_i \cap V^+_j) \bigg ] \cap \bigg [ \bigcup_{\substack{i= 1, \ldots, m \\ j = 1, \ldots, n}} (U_i \cap V_j) \bigg ]^-.
\end{align}
$$

---

However, I'm stuck because  $U^+_i \cap V^+_j \neq (U_i \cap V_j)^+$. Could you please elaborate on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space. A collection $\mathcal B \subset \tau$ is called a ***base*** of $\tau$ if every open set can be represented as a union of some subfamily of $\mathcal B$. Equivalently, a family $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of $X$ is a base for the topology $\tau$ if and only if $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \tau$ and for every $U \in \tau$ and $x \in U$ there is $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B \subseteq U$.

---

We want to prove that $\mathcal B_2$ is a base of our Vietoris topology $\mathcal T$. Clearly, $\mathcal B_2 \subset \mathcal B_1 \subset \mathcal T$. Now we fix $x \in U \in \mathcal T$. Because $\mathcal B$ is a subbase of $\mathcal T$, there is $V \in \mathcal B$ such that $x \in V$. The claim then follows from $\mathcal B \subset \mathcal B_2$.